# View tabs during ctrl-tab in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

In Windows, when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> together, then repeatedly press <kbd>Tab</kbd> while holding down on the <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you see a list of all open windows and you can toggle between them.

In Notepad++ and other editors, you can do the same thing with editor tabs using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combo.

**Question:**
Although Sublime Text supports basic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it doesn't support the ability to view a list of all the tabs while keeping the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> tab held down (as does Notepad++). Is there some plugin that provides this functionality, or an alternate key-combination I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sublime text you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to show a list of open files ordered by LRU (as in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> document switching). But it requires more keystrokes than the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> way.

Comment: But I agree with you. A document switching without an ordered list of documents is annoying and a bit useless. I have been looking for years for this feature. For me, an editor that doesn't support this is a broken editor.

Comment: Looks like that's as good as I'll get.